# Evaluating the indefinite integral $\int \tan \sqrt {x} \,dx$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

> $$\int \tan \sqrt {x} \,dx$$

I was trying to solve this. But it took very long time and three pages. Could someone please tell me how to solve this quickly.

Comment: I don't believe there's a closed-form expression for this integral.

Comment: Are you sure that it's an indefinite integral?

Comment: Yeah. Indefinite. It took long time to solve. But i did it. I want to know a shoter method.

Comment: you will get the PolyLog function

Comment: I don't know what is polylog. Could you please explain that

Comment: @AVIE make sure that you didn't go wrong somewhere because there isn't a closed form for that integral. As Dr. Graubner pointed out, the result contains $\operatorname{Li_2}$.

Comment: That means we can't solve this right?

Comment: Thank you all! Appreciate what you did! Thank you  again!!!

Comment: @AVIE no; it means that the solution cannot be represented in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: Ahhhhh okey :)thank you

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the trig functions that cannot be integrated in

the usual way. I suggest using Reimann sums to approximate or other methods.

Comment: Choose your words carefully. The function is indeed integrable, in the sense that the Riemann sums converge. It's not expressible in terms of elementary functions however.

Answer (score 1):

I fiddled with this one a little bit:
\begin{align}
u & = \sqrt x \\[10pt]
u^2 & = x \\[10pt]
2u\,du & = dx \\[10pt]
\int \tan \sqrt x \, dx & = 2 \int u\ \ \underbrace{\tan u\  du}_{dv} = \underbrace{2\int u\,dv = 2uv - 2\int v\,du}_\text{integration by parts with $dv$ as below}. \tag 1 \\[20pt]
dv & = \tan u \, du \\
v & = -\log|\cos u| \\[10pt]
\text{So the expression in $(1)$ is }
& -2u \log |\cos u| + 2\int \log |\cos u| \, du.
\end{align}

Then I resorted to [Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+log+cos%28x%29+dx).

Comment: Could you please explain the fourth line

Comment: @AVIE : The fourth line is integration by parts. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Thank you!! Sir. Appreciate your work